# is it possible for a linux vm on an android phone to deliver web content to the mobile browser?

Tags: android, linux, browser, virtual-machine

You can run a linux vm on an android phone or tablet and connect to it via a vnc or ssh client. Would it be possible to make the linux vm a server and deliver content to the mobile browser from it? How could that be done?

Comment: Have you tried just using ``127.0.0.1``?

Comment: I don't own an android phone. =)

Comment: The android SDK also include an android phone emulator. Generally, you develop your apps inside an emulator not in a real phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve web content from the application itself (without a web server), or you can take a mini servlet container like [i-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/).

Have a look at [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), on how to embed the mobile broser (with javascript APIs) inside your app.

BTW, it looks like somebody also ported [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) to Android: [Limbo PC Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.max2idea.android.limbo.main&hl=it).

So you can combine the above things, and make your app.

Comment: Thanks, these seem neat but more limited than an actual (but low powered) linux server on my phone that I can use with any framework I want, with several webapps as well as an ssh connection with emacs sharing the same set of files etc. (Please correct me if I'm wrong, I don't know much about web or android development.)

Comment: Limbo PC Emulator asserts to be able to run a complete DSL (Damn Small Linux) inside of an android device. Which means, with user interface basic office suite, and terminal and ssh too. I'm pretty sure that running a statically compiled apache won't be harder than that. BTW, I doubt you can use your phone. If you are planning to use your phone as desktop computer, I think you'll be disappointed. But I think that serving a webapp from an android phone may be feasible.

Comment: No. I only plan to access the vm via the browser (for simple web apps) and an ssh app. Linux on android supports a lot of different distros: http://linuxonandroid.org